# pass parameter to kendo dialog jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm trying to pass value to kendo dialog form. please see my below code. I need to pass "id" value to dialog box.How can i achieved that? Thanks !
Button code:

```
<span class="k-icon k-i-plus-circle" onclick="jobSplitDialogOpen('#: id #'); return false" title="Split Job"></span>
```

Dialog html:

```
<div id="jobSplit-dialog" title="Job Split" style="background:#fffef8;overflow:hidden;display:none">
        <span>#: id #</span>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn ez-btn ez-btn-cancel" onclick="onjobSplitDialogClose(); return false" />
        <input type="button" id="apply" value="Apply" class="btn ez-btn ez-btn-primary" onclick="jobSplitSave(); return false" />&nbsp;
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var jobSplitDialog = $("#jobSplit-dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: "auto",
            width: "auto",
            modal: true,
        });

    function jobSplitDialogOpen(id) {
        console.log("Job Id"+id);            
        jobSplitDialog.parent().addClass("ez-dialog");            
        jobSplitDialog.dialog('open');
        $('#apply').focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. Here is one way to accomplish what you're looking for (I just set the id to 3 in the span onclick here, you'll want to revert that to be your id value):

Code:

```
<span onclick="jobSplitDialogOpen('3'); return false;" title="Split Job">CLICK HERE</span>

<div id="dialog"></div>

<script id="jobSplitTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <span>#= id #</span>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn ez-btn ez-btn-cancel" onclick="onjobSplitDialogClose(); return false" />
        <input type="button" id="apply" value="Apply" class="btn ez-btn ez-btn-primary" onclick="jobSplitSave(); return false" />&nbsp;
</script>


<script>
var dlg = $("#dialog").kendoDialog({
  visible: false,
  height: "200px",
  width: "300px",
  modal: true,
});

function jobSplitDialogOpen(id) {
  console.log("Job Id "+id);            

  var scriptTemplate = kendo.template($("#jobSplitTemplate").html());
  var scriptData = { id: id };

  dlg.html(scriptTemplate(scriptData));

  dlg.data("kendoDialog").open();
}
</script>
```

and here it is running in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kp5Lhson/

Comment: Hi @G_P, Thank you so much for your solutions. I'm having another issue like kendo control I'm not getting on modal form.  What could be the issue ? 
<input id="JobSplitStartdate" title="datepicker" class="ez-datepicker" />
$("#JobSplitStartdate").kendoDatePicker({
                value: new Date(),
                format: 'dd/MM/yyyy'

            }).data("kendoDatePicker");
        });

Comment: If I take dropdown in the modal It's not binding. What could be the reason ? Thanks !

Comment: @RafiqzzamanLiton Please ask a new question for this separate issue, and post your code.

Comment: @G-P I have added one question. could you see this issue please . Thanks 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64008745/kendoui-dropdown-filter-doesnt-work-with-jquery